# Load a ID2D1Bitmap from a .bmp file

Tags: direct2d

I'm searching for quite a while now, how to load an ID2D1Bitmap from a .bmp file but only found lots of stuff about loading it from for example an .jpg file. Thanks for answers!

Comment: Why don't you try your findings against the code you found for JPEG files and your BMP file? It is WIC loading image files for D2D and it supports a range of formats, so there is no much of a difference or format dependent code.

Comment: Yes, that works just fine, I just wonder if there isn't a shorter way to load the image since it's already in a bitmap format

Comment: Yes and no. Yes because the file is unlikely to have compression of sorts. No because it still might have an incompatible bitmap format and then D2D pixel layout is not necessarily the same as in the file, and then once again you are loading through an intermediary API here... so there does not have to be a shorter way. Well you could extract pixels from file, then map D2D bitmap data and load those pixels into locked memory fitting the data but you will quickly realize that that JPEG way was shorter...

Comment: That's what loading it does. Why would you try to implement it yourself?

Comment: I wanted to safe performance if I'd load a great amount of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was just answered, thanks:

Yes and no. Yes because the file is unlikely to have compression of sorts. No because it still might have an incompatible bitmap format and then D2D pixel layout is not necessarily the same as in the file, and then once again you are loading through an intermediary API here... so there does not have to be a shorter way. Well you could extract pixels from file, then map D2D bitmap data and load those pixels into locked memory fitting the data but you will quickly realize that that JPEG way was shorter... – Roman R.